# Primefaces dataTable only adding a single row

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I've been digging through the archives to find an answer that might help, but nothing really seems to apply.

I have a page in jsf with nested dataTables that is holding a list from the backing bean.  The page seems to be holding the data without any issues, but when I attempt to add rows either of my dataTables using the p:collector Primefaces object, my dataTable only ever displays a single row.  I am always adding an empty object to both lists.

The objects contained in the list are custom objects that implement Serializable.

My backing bean is ConversationScoped, and the data in the backing bean is instantiated when the conversation is started.

Here is my main page:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/pageLayout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="pageContent">

        <h:form id="genericWorkflowMainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:panel id="actionList">
                <div align="right">
                    <p:commandButton id="addActionButton" value="Add Action" update="actionTable" 
                                     action="#{createGenericWorkflowBean.addAction}" ajax="false">
                        <p:collector id="addActionCollector" value="#{createGenericWorkflowBean.actionRow}" 
                                     addTo="#{createGenericWorkflowBean.genericWorkflowData.actionGroup.actionCompletionList}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>
                <h:dataTable id="actionTable" var="actions"
                             value="#{createGenericWorkflowBean.genericWorkflowData.actionGroup.actionCompletionList}">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Action  " /> 
                        <h:inputTextarea id="actionText" value="#{actions.actionRecord.actionText}" />
                        <br/>
                        <p:panel id ="actioneePanel">
                            <div align="right">
                                <p:commandButton id="addApproverButton" value="Add Approver" onclick="addApprover.show()"/>
                            </div>
                            <h:dataTable value="#{actions.actionRecord.actionees}" id="actioneeListValues" var="actioneeRecord">
                                <h:column>

                                    <h:outputText id="actioneeLabel" value="Actionee  " />
                                    <h:outputText id="actionee" value="#{actioneeRecord.user.user.name}" />

                                    <h:outputText id="actioneeCommentlabel" value="Comments  " rendered="#{actioneeRecord.user.display}"/>
                                    <h:inputTextarea id ="actioneeComment" value="#{actioneeRecord.userComment}" rendered="#{actioneeRecord.user.display}"/>

                                    <br/>
                                    <p:commandLink id="removeActionee" value="Remove" update="actioneeListValues" rendered="#{!actioneeRecord.user.display}">
                                        <p:collector value="#{actioneeRecord}" removeFrom="#{actions.actionRecord.actionees}"/>
                                    </p:commandLink>

                                </h:column>

                            </h:dataTable>

                            <p:dialog id="addApprover" header="Add Approver" widgetVar="addApprover" modal="false" closable="false"
                                      resizable="false" width="250">
                                <div>
                                    <p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteApprover" value="#{createGenericWorkflowBean.newApprover}"
                                                    /**//>
                                    <br/>
                                    <p:commandButton id="addNewApprover" title="Add Approver" value="Add"
                                                     update="actioneeListValues" onclick="addApprover.hide()" ajax="false"
                                                     action="#{createGenericWorkflowBean.addApprover()}">
                                        <p:collector value="#{createGenericWorkflowBean.newApprover}" 
                                                     addTo="#{actions.actionRecord.actionees}"/>

                                    </p:commandButton>

                                </div>
                            </p:dialog>
                        </p:panel>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </p:panel>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Below are the parts of my backing bean that relate to the p:collector adding and removing portions of the list.

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CreateGenericWorkflowBean extends WorkflowBean {

    @Inject
    Conversation conversation;

    private Actionee newApprover;

    private ActionCompletionRecord actionRow = new ActionCompletionRecord();

    private Actionee actioneeRow = new Actionee();

    public GenericWorkflowData getGenericWorkflowData() {
        return (GenericWorkflowData) getData();
    }

    public void addApprover() {

        setNewApprover(new Actionee());

    }

    public void addAction() {
        actionRow = new ActionCompletionRecord();
    }

}
```

I am still learning JSF and Primefaces, so I do not know if I've done something that will just never work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Matt Tatham

Comment: That's way too much code. Please isolate the problem in smallest possible but complete single XHTML page and single backing bean. For example, are the `<ui:define name="windowTitle">` tag and the `style="border:none"` attribute of the `<p:dataTable>` absolutely necessary in order to reproduce exactly the same problem? No? Just omit it. The same applies to all of those other unnecessary tags, attributes, properties, etc. Provide the smallest possible code containing **only** the code which is absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem ourselves by just copypasting and running the code.

Comment: Removed all the chaff.  Sorry, I'm still very new at posting issues here.

Answer (score -1):

The entity class  has the @override methods, which were generated while creating new entity through create new entity wizard. remove all the overridden methods from the entity and save it. Thats all. Now it will work.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.